# Why am I getting a NullPointerException when creating a Swing component?

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

The error occurs when creating the Box object.

```
    public void drawBoard(Board board){
    for(int row = 0; row < 8; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < 8; col++){
            Box box = new Box(board.getSquare(col, row).getColour(), col, row);
            squarePanel[col][row].add(box);
        }
    }
```

Board is given from the Game constructor here (another class):

```
public Game() throws Throwable{
    View graphics = new View();
    board = new Board();
    board.setDefault();
    graphics.drawBoard(board);
}
```

The Board constructor looks like this:

```
public Board(){
    grid = new Square[COLUMNS][ROWS];
    for(int row = 0; row < 8; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < 8; col++){
            grid[col][row] = new Square(this);
        }
    }
    for(int row = 0; row < 8; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < 4; col++){
            int odd = 2*col + 1;
            int even = 2*col;
            getSquare(odd, row).setColour(Color.BLACK);
            getSquare(even, row).setColour(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the Box class:

```
class Box extends JComponent{
Color boxColour;
int col, row;
public Box(Color boxColour, int col, int row){
    this.boxColour = boxColour;
    this.col = col;
    this.row = row;
    repaint();
}
public void paint(Graphics drawBox){
    drawBox.setColor(boxColour);
    drawBox.drawRect(50*col, 50*row, 50, 50);
    drawBox.fillRect(50*col, 50*row, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

So while looping through the array, it uses the two integers as coordinates to create the Box. 
The coordinates are referenced and then repaint() is run.
The box also gets the colour, using the two integers, from the Square in the Board class.
Since the colour is already set, before the drawBoard(board) method is run, that shouldn't be a problem, right?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at View.drawBoard(View.java:38)
    at Game.<init>(Game.java:21)
    at Game.main(Game.java:14)
```

The relevant part of `Square`

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class Square {

    private Piece piece;
    private Board board;
    private Color squareColour;

public Square(Board board){
    this.board = board;
}

public void setColour(Color squareColour){
    this.squareColour = squareColour;
}

public Color getColour(){
    return squareColour;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace with the NullPointerException in it?

Comment: Not sure, is that the error in the console?

Comment: @Alex, yes, the thing that starts "java.lang.NullPointerException" and has a bunch of line numbers in it - all of that.

Comment: Please post the code for `Square`

Comment: Right, any particular part of it?

Comment: Given that stack trace, either the `board` variable, the result of `board.getSquare` or the `squarePanel` variable is null. Can you add some debugging statements to print out the values of each of those? e.g. `System.out.println(board); System.out.println(squarePanel); System.out.println("Row " + row + ", col " + col); System.out.println(board.getSquare(col, row));`

Comment: Alternatively, step through the code with a debugger and look at those values. Also, if you could mark line 38 in View.java that would make it easier for us to find the problem.

Comment: Can you tell us what Board.setDefault() is doing?

Comment: Line 38 is the 4th line in my first code snippet. Also... I think I might have figured it out, embarrasing.
I've thought until recently that doing Object[] object = new Object[i] actually creates i objects in the Object[]. Surely it's because I haven't actually created the JPanels.
All I did was JPanel[][] squarePanel = new JPanel[8][8].
So what I have to do is loop through squarePanel and create the JPanels, right?

Comment: If the offending line is `Box box = new Box(board.getSquare(col, row).getColour(), col, row);` then your JPanel[][] is irrelevant.

Comment: Marking your question down as you mislead everyone as to which line of code was causing the NPE.

Comment: How did I mislead everyone?
As you said, it's that line which is the offending line. Are you saying I should've pasted my whole whole code here?
I just pasted the relevant code, and as I said. Line 4 in the first snippet is what is Line 38 in my code and what supposedly caused the NPE. I thought it was solved since it doesn't give me any NPE when I now try run the code. However, the boxes don't show up at all. Which is weird. I tried switching the visibility modifier of the box and all JPanels to true but still nothing.

Comment: So if it isn't that JPanel[][] was null, what might have caused the NPE?

Comment: @Kurt: setDefault() assigns the default Pieces to the Squares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your drawBoard() method, there are 2 places which could cause the NullPointerException

```
Box box = new Box(board.getSquare(col, row).getColour(), col, row);
```

if board is null, or the result of getSquare is null then you will see a NPE.

The other area, and a very common place people throw NullPointerExceptions is

```
squarePanel[col][row].add(box);
```

Since you have not shown us how you declare this I will assume the following, you have create a JPanel, in this panel you have not created a new instance for the 8x8 array. So when you add() the new box, it will throw the NullPointerException

It would help more, if you could also tell us what line `38` is in your `View` class

Comment: Yes that's the case, silly me. Should've checked the code closer. I didn't actually create any new instances of JPanel in the 8x8 array.
It works now.

Answer (score 0):

A guess because you haven't provided the full source - but for the loops you seem to have hard coded in the number of rows and columns, but for declaring the 2D grid array you've used two constants.

Depending on your implementation of getSquare and if these constants differ to your hard coded values, that could be what's causing the issue.

Comment: The two constants are both equal to 8. Also getSquare takes the two indexes given to it and gives the Square at that place in the array.